# C# - To close a NetworkStream, call stream.Close or socket.Shutdown?

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, networkstream

I was wondering if anyone knew the best way to dispose of a class that uses a Socket object and NetworkStream object? The class in question has an instance of NetworkStream and an instance of Socket that's used to create the NetworkStream.

```
this.socket = new Socket(
                           AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                           SocketType.Stream,
                           ProtocolType.Tcp)
                        {
                            ReceiveBufferSize = 65536,
                            SendBufferSize = 150
                        };

this.socket.Connect(
                        new IPEndPoint(                                                                   
                              IPAddress.Parse(
                                          Properties.Settings.Default.MpsServer2),
                                          Properties.Settings.Default.MpsPort2));

this.stream = new NetworkStream(
                         this.socket, true);
```

In my Dispose method, should I do this?

```
this.stream.Close();
this.socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
this.socket.Close();
```

Is all of this necessary or is it overkill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Socket` does not dispose of the associated `NetworkStream`. I fired up [reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1) too be certain. (a tool to analyze .NET dlls and thet .NET libraries. Great tool. You have to end of the month to download the free version before it goes fully. commercial).

However, according to both [the MDSN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te7e60bx.aspx) and reflector the stream will close the socket but only if it has ownership of the socket. You can set that as the second parameter in the overloaded constructor.

You have to call `Shutdown` in any case because if [flushes the data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.shutdown.aspx). If you don't, you could lose data.

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer only because it has the most documentation going for it. I wonder if the stream's Dispose method might do the job, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of info about exactly what it will do.

Answer (score 1):

Both `Socket` and `Stream` Implement `IDisposable` so you can just call `.Dispose()` on each object.  The Dispose method should handle closing and other actions necessary for disposal.

```
this.stream.Dispose(); 
this.socket.Dispose();
```

For Example, this is the disassembled `Dispose` method from the stream class:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: You can't call `Dispose` on a socket. Only `Close`.

Comment: the implementation of IDisposable of the Socket is explicit, meaning it has no "public" Dispose method, you would have to cast Socket to IDisposable to be able to call Dispose, e.g. ((IDisposable)socket).Dispose() ...

Comment: using (var socket = new Socket()) {..} will call the Dispose()

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation in MSDN, calling stream.Close() "Closes the current stream and releases any resources (such as sockets and file handles) associated with the current stream.", which tells me that stream.Close() also disposes the socket. You'd still have to call socket.Shutdown() though.

Anyway, IMHO the safest way is using "using", it keeps you on the safe site :)

```
using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
                        {
                            ReceiveBufferSize = 65536,
                            SendBufferSize = 150
                        };) {
  socket.Connect(
    new IPEndPoint(
      IPAddress.Parse(
        Properties.Settings.Default.MpsServer2), Properties.Settings.Default.MpsPort2));

  using (var stream = new NetworkStream(socket, true) {
    // do something with the stream here
  }

  socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
}
```